# At which voltage is battery dead?

Tags: battery

I have not driven my Tacoma 06 for a year, because of a mechanical issue I need to work on, and when I tried to turn it on, it wouldn't start and there would be no noise at all coming from the starter. I measured the voltage and it was 3V.

I tried to jump start it from a Mazda 3 and it would start making frequent clicking noise but no more than that. Is this battery dead and should it be replaced or is there a way to recharge it?

Comment: It is a chemistry thing , it will be always be  close to 12 V ( with an open circuit).  It is the amperage it is able to produce that determines condition.

Comment: Why can't you try to recharge it? You do that with a battery charger. If it won't take a charge then replace it.

Comment: Left flat that long. Buy and fit a new one, then if you won't be driving it much also buy and fit a battery tender.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - That's not accurate. Batteries lose voltage as they become more flat. When fully charged, they should be ~13.1vdc (when in good shape).